# Django conversations - get_or_create MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create simple chat system, my models:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, related_name='conversation')
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my view:

```
def conversation(request, username):
    recipient = User.objects.get(username=username)
    conversation, created = Conversation.objects.get_or_create(
        users__in=[recipient, request.user]
    )

    if created:
        conversation.users.add([recipient, request.user])
```

I want create users connection by create conversation with manytomany field.
When i go to /conversations/user_name get_or_create check if conversation exists and if not then create new conversation with current logged user and user from url.

My problem is:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /conversations/user_name
get() returned more than one Conversation -- it returned 2!
```

How can i solve it? Probably its problem with this manytomany field.. How i can limit users__id lookup to 1?

Comment: The conversation already exists and there are two objects of Conversations... That's why the error occurred...

Answer (score 1):

[get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) isn't suitable for this.

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

You don't have a unique key in your table. And the nature of your app is such that a unique key cannot be used. At the same time, a chat message very very occasionally getting repeated isn't a big deal. So just go ahead and create the object without bothering to check for existence.

Also note that checking for existing using a select and then doing the create would be futile. The race condition mentioned would kick in and you will still end up with duplicates.