# get() returned more than one Model -- it returned 4! - but only 1 Model in db

Tags: django, race-condition

In a Django view, I'm getting a MultipleObjectsReturned error using a get_or_create. [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960593/multipleobjectsreturned-with-get-or-create) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620205/django-get-returned-more-than-one) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354440/django-conversations-get-or-create-multipleobjectsreturned) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289037/multipleobjectsreturned-at-cart-in-django) about this, but those people seem to be using this construct wrongly. I *think* that I'm using it correctly, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey('app.OtherModel', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    field3 = models.JSONField()
    field4 = models.JSONField()

    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Date updated'), auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Date created'), default=timezone.now)

    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1', 'field2'], name='unique_model'),
        ]
```

And this code in my view:

```
o, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(field1=value1, field2='value2',
    defaults={'field3': '...', 'field4': '...'})
```

So the `get` is performed on the two fields that are in the `UniqueConstraint`, the other fields are listed in the `defaults` part (in case the `create` is required).

The MultipleObjectsReturned is thrown on that last line, when Django performs the `get` part of the `get_or_create`, but only in some rare cases - most of the time this construct works well.

The view is actually a handler for AWS's SNS event messages for SES, handling delivery delays, bounces and complaints. In *theory* it should not happen that this view is called exactly twice, causing a race-condition. When I check the server logs, I indeed do *not* see multiple calls to this view at the time this error is thrown. (Only one email was sent and SNS tries resending the SNS event only every 20 seconds.)

[This article](https://adriennedomingus.com/blog/the-perils-of-getorcreate-race-conditions) explains the problem well, but unfortunately does not provide a solution for me.

Note that sometimes "-- it returned 2!", sometimes "-- it returned 3!" and sometimes "-- it returned 4!"

Also note that the error is thrown with fields that are *not* None: the `ForeignKey` of field1 points to a row in "OtherModel" and the `CharField` of field2 contains a string.

And the kicker is: when I run that same get_or_create in ipython in production, using the exact same values as mentioned in the error (in Sentry), no error is thrown and the `get` is performed correctly.

What and why is this going wrong in the view?

I'm using Django 3.2.2 and Postgres 11.10.

Comment: The database considers `NULL`/`None` not to be the same as `NULL`/`None`, so if you have two `NULL`s, the database still assumes the unique constraint is satisfied.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good point, I've updated the question.

Comment: The `ForeignKey` of `field1` being `None` regularly while `field2` being not unique caused the trouble with the constraint. I've added another field that is unique on its own and replaced `field1` in the constraint with that one, updated the `get_or_create` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an SQL database system, `NULL` is not equal to `NULL` (usually `NULL = NULL` returns `NULL`), therefore if the fields are *nullable*, it means that the other field can be repeated an arbitrary number of times.

What we can do is implement three constraints: uniques on the two fields, uniqness on one field if the other is `NULL` and vice-versa, so then the constraints look like:

```
from django.db.models import Q, UniqueConstraint

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(
        'app.OtherModel',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    # …

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1', 'field2'], name='unique_model1'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1'], condition=Q(field2=None), name='unique_model2'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['field2'], condition=Q(field1=None), name='unique_mode3'),
        ]
```

Not all database backend however might enforce unique constraints with a condition.